# JAVAFX Tableview Split cell (or) Cell Span

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

How to put common table heading for two columns in JAVAFX 
Like the image below

[image]

**Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks!**

Comment: Are you are looking for [nested columns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJABHBEH)?

Comment: Two columns with one header, like the image

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code

```
TableColumn parentCol = new TableColumn("Parent");
TableColumn firstCol = new TableColumn("First");
TableColumn secondCol = new TableColumn("Second");

parentCol.getColumns().addAll(firstCol , secondCol );
```

Comment: you can refer below link for populating data  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400367/javafx-span-tableview-merge-cells-by-mapentries